# How to style input type file using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/5WcFj/

I have an input field which is in the type "file".

```
     <input type="text" name="fake_section" class="fake_section"><button class="fake_section">Choose Photo</button>
     <input type="file" style="display:none;" name="file" id="file" value="Choose Photo" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" /> 
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And i use the following css

```
input[type="file"] {
    width:50%;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:thin solid #ddd;   
}
```

i got my output like following

[image]
But actually i **want the output like,**
[image]
Another problem is that i only **want to choose the "jpeg and png" image files**, but this input field accept all the file type. And i try this in both the browsers Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="fake_section" class="fake_section">
    <input type="button" class="fake_section" value="Choose Photo"/>
<input type="file" style="display:none;" name="file" id="file" value="Choose Photo" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

JS

```
$('.fake_section').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#file').trigger('click');    
});

$('#file').change(function(e){
    var filename = $(this).val();
    var ext = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if( $.inArray( ext, ['gif','jpg','jpeg'] ) == -1 ){
        alert('not valid!');
    }
    else{
        $('input[name="fake_section"]').val(filename);
    }
});
```

Try like this

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/5WcFj/2/

Comment: but here no files are selected into texbox??

Comment: But i have a question can i post the file from a form  to a model by using this way

Comment: @Parvathiiiii yes ofcause, because i just hide the filetype, form definitely pass the file type informations.

Comment: but in my case when click to choose the photo it is directly go to submit button without selecting photo?!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45429/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-parvathiiiii)

Comment: <input type="button" class="fake_section" value="Choose Photo"/> is solving my problem

Comment: @Parvathiiiii glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to validate the file

```
var ext = $('#file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
   alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question, you can choose which files appear in the open box by using the `accept` attribute on the `input`.

See the [official W3C reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept).

Note, however, that the page suggests you can choose png and jpeg files by using `accept="image/png,image/jpeg"`, and that will not work in all browsers. Only in Chrome actually. So it's better to put `accept="image/*"` (for all image files) which does work in the majority of browsers.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4L36/4/).

You also had troubles with the submit button, but that was caused by the fact that `<input type="button">` is not the same as `<button>`. One doesn't submit, the other does.
Here is a quick list for reference.

`<input type="submit">`  submits
`<input type="button">`  doesn't submit
`<button type="submit">` submits
`<button type="button">` doesn't submit
`<button>`               submits